# Wordpress Multisite: Duplicate single Post from one site to another

Tags: wordpress, plugins, copy, duplicates

I am searching for a wordpress plugin which enables a function to copy a post from one page in the multisite network to another.

Does anybody know such a plugin?

I just found plugins which enables duplicates within a site or duplicate whole sites in the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can choose your single post by a combination of category, date, author, and status, you can use the built-in EXPORT function  (Tools > Export on the dashboard menu) to export just the post you want.

Then you can import it into the other WP installation.

This has worked well for me. One of the good things about it is that it works both on self-hosted WP installations and on WordPress.com installations.

Comment: Hi Ollie, thanks so much for this answer! I tried the export tool right now and I am only able to filter standard post types like posts and pages. I would also like to filter and export entries which have a custom post_type... But I think there will we an answer in the internet :)  PS: Will vote for your answer when i reached 15 rep

Comment: On my installations, there's a pull down menu that allows choosing custom post types for export.

Answer (score 0):

I note this plugin is available: Multisite Post Duplicator: https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-post-duplicator/ .

Have not used it, but reviews are good.